# how to create a data.frame in R from a complex JSON file and loop of files with this

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I am kind of new to the loops in R and also to transform from Json to data.frame thing.

I have a data in json file like this:

```
{
"players": {
    "111111": {
        "tLastEvent": 1432523322.429,
        "tActive": 30793.195000172,
        "tSocial": 1915.0230002403,
        "nBlockBreak": 2315,
        "nBlockPlace": 3051,
        "sMove": 141554.58326606,
        "loc": {
            "w": "111111",
            "x": 222222,
            "y": 222222,
            "z": 2222222
        },
        "social": {
            "22222": 42.579999923706,
            "333333": 2318.8910028934,
            "44444": 440.19000005722,
            "55555": 5417.4040002823,
            "66666": 913.04000043869,
            "7777": 1737.2639997005,
            "88888": 419.68400025368,
            "6666666": 972.16700005531,
            "999999": 241.88300061226
        }
```

}

Currently I got some good ideas from here and I got this far

```
origininfo<-fromJSON("stats_100_players.json")  
socialpl<-origininfo$players[[1]]$tSocial 
socialinfo <- as.data.frame(lapply(socialpl,rbind))
colnames(socialinfo, prefix = "social")
```

As a result I get a small one that for that row:

```
    structure.1915.0230002403...Dim...c.1L..1L..
1
1915.023
```

Of course I have more players and the structure is the same, but how should I collapse all?

So Here is my other questions, What can I change to add the other variables? How can I do this for 30 files without having to write the code each time (all have the same structure?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

For the function in the answer:

```
   {
    "players": {
        "209": {
            "tLastEvent": 1428843834.06,
            "tActive": 38087.053002357,
            "tSocial": 12595.439997435,
            "nBlockBreak": 1203,
            "nBlockPlace": 1259,
            "sMove": 159226.12087558,
            "loc": {
                "w": "279576",
                "x": -150.46255768861,
                "y": 105.531226699,
                "z": 11111
            },
            "social": {
                "279578": 4131.6009998322,
                "279581": 578.5170006752,
                "279579": 104.48099970818,
                "279586": 194.46699929237,
                "279592": 1223.5819990635,
                "279594": 657.69799971581,
                "279738": 979.95199990273,
                "279740": 3092.1240000725,
                "279959": 114.17499995232,
                "282352": 6.5269999504089,
                "282354": 454.35900020599,
                "283245": 21.192000150681,
                "283257": 185.67299985886,
                "283262": 198.18899941444,
                "283280": 33.197999954224,
                "284033": 200.12299990654,
                "284035": 419.58199977875
            }
        },
        "210": {
            "tLastEvent": 1429132071.012,
            "tActive": 88717.513002872,
            "tSocial": 10737.395000458,
            "nBlockBreak": 23681,
            "nBlockPlace": 20924,
            "sMove": 106778.98294399,
            "loc": {
                "w": "2222",
                "x": -1693.8889200061,
                "y": 71,
                "z": 1111
            },
            "social": {
                "279577": 4131.6009998322,
                "279579": 271.47599959373,
                "279959": 4425.5970008373,
                "279988": 1.0309998989105,
                "279738": 325.50400018692,
                "279740": 1133.4730000496,
                "280310": 1.0169999599457,
                "282301": 1.0130000114441,
                "282354": 415.23199987411,
                "283257": 1.0079998970032,
                "284033": 20.141000270844,
                "284035": 10.302000045776
            }
        },
        "211": {
            "tLastEvent": 1428688172,
            "tActive": 1059.9219996929,
            "tSocial": 375.95699930191,
            "nBlockBreak": 219,
            "nBlockPlace": 6,
            "sMove": 883.21344060341,
            "loc": {
                "w": "279576",
                "x": -130.9778811327,
                "y": 81,
                "z": 111111
            },
            "social": {
                "279578": 271.47599959373,
                "279577": 104.48099970818
            }
        },
        "212": {
            "tLastEvent": 1428254467.317,
            "tActive": 2135.6659991741,
            "tSocial": 659.75200080872,
            "nBlockBreak": 40,
            "nBlockPlace": 20,
            "sMove": 4789.0751244105,
            "loc": {
                "w": "22222",
                "x": 1269.528314042,
                "y": 72,
                "z": 1111111
            },
            "social": {
                "279577": 578.5170006752,
                "279592": 81.235000133514
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a defined function with `lapply()` on the list of json files pulled from a directory. In building  the list for dataframe conversion, you would need to `unlist()` the nested items: *loc* and *social*:

```
library(jsonlite)

mypath = "path/to/json/files"
jsonfiles <- list.files(path = mypath, pattern=".json", full.names=TRUE)

jsonparse <- function(file){
  origininfo <- fromJSON(file) 

  tempList <- lapply(seq_along(origininfo), function(i){
    temp <- c(list(player = names(origininfo[[i]])),
              origininfo$players[[i]][1:6], 
              lapply(origininfo$players[[i]]$loc, unlist),
              lapply(origininfo$players[[i]]$social, unlist))
    df <- data.frame(temp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })

  jsondf <- do.call(rbind, tempList)
}

dfList <- lapply(jsonfiles, jsonparse)

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
colnames(df) <- colnames(df, prefix="social")
```

**Output** *(using example posted)*

```
str(finaldf)

#  'data.frame' : 1 obs. of  20 variables:
#  $ player     : chr "111111"
#  $ tLastEvent : num 1.43e+09
#  $ tActive    : num 30793
#  $ tSocial    : num 1915
#  $ nBlockBreak: int 2315
#  $ nBlockPlace: int 3051
#  $ sMove      : num 141555
#  $ w          : chr "111111"
#  $ x          : int 222222
#  $ y          : int 222222
#  $ z          : int 2222222
#  $ X22222     : num 42.6
#  $ X333333    : num 2319
#  $ X44444     : num 440
#  $ X55555     : num 5417
#  $ X66666     : num 913
#  $ X7777      : num 1737
#  $ X88888     : num 420
#  $ X6666666   : num 972
#  $ X999999    : num 242
```

Comment: Hi @ParFait Thanks a lot it really was really helpful for the data.frame.  I only have a problem with the lapply, It appears that the line has a problem and need to be debug   **Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 1, 0**

Comment: Carefully check if all player json files in directory are actually exact structure. If you have other non-player .json in directory, move them to another folder. You can also try `print(origininfo)` inside jsonparse fct to see each json content and identify ones that deter from structure.

Comment: Its running with the files now, but there is a problem with the other players in the same file. the data frame takes the name different but the rest players have the same value has the first one. For example below.               `"","player","tLastEvent","tActive","tSocial",
"1","277947",1434767680.747,13653.170000076,
"2","277971",1434767680.747,13653.170000076,
"3","277972",1434767680.747,13653.170000076,
"4","278022",1434767680.747,13653.170000076`  I try to change the function, but i getting errors with the rows. Thanks again @Parfait

Comment: I thought your posted json was the exact structure in all 30 some files where each file corresponds to one player. So now there can multiple players in one file (i.e., length of `origininfo` can be greater than 1)?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry Was my first post here. Most of the file have at least 8 to 10 players. But that varies on each file. I try to unlist player too, but didn't work.

Comment: See edit with updated `jsonparse()` fct. Basically, within each json file, you will run an an inner `lapply()` across the length of `origininfo` to capture all players. Outer `lapply()` binds across files.

Comment: I just finished running and fixing some issues, regarding the function I still have  the problem of the repeated rows [link]http://tinypic.com/r/4j8dg9/9[link] but I could manage the **rbind** problem by using **rbind.fill** Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest development version of [tidyjson](https://github.com/jeremystan/tidyjson) which you can install with devtools.

Here is what the code could look like, if you are starting with a character vector `json_files` of paths to your JSON files:

```
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)

# Read the data in using readr and flatten to a character vector
json <- json_files %>% map_chr(read_file)

# Parse the json and gather the players by number
players <- json %>% enter_object("players") %>% gather_object("player.num")

# Spread out all the top level fields
main <- players %>% spread_all(recursive = FALSE)

# Spread out the location data
locs <- players %>% enter_object("loc") %>% spread_all

# Gather social data
social <- players %>% enter_object("social") %>%
  gather_object("social.key") %>% append_values_number("social.value")
```

You can then manipulate or join `main`, `locs` and `social` as needed on `player.num` if they are unique across documents or `document.id` and `player.num` if not using [dp\
lyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html).

Note that I took some liberties naming columns (like `"social.key"`) without knowing what they really mean.